# List apps (not) supporting adb backup

Tags: backup

Is there a reliable way to identify all the installed apps that do (not) support `adb backup`?

I am running a LinageOS and seem to be forced to reinstall to upgrade. I would like to check which apps I need to manually back up or where I need to be prepared to lose data.

---

I found this script, but it does not properly identify Signal as not supporting backups... https://sourceforge.net/projects/no-adb-backup-app-lister/files/

Comment: Is your device rooted? If yes may be an app like OAndBackupX or NeoBackup would be helpful, even if such apps can not backup all apps because cryptographic keys in `AndroidKeyStore` are protected as far as I know.

Comment: No, my device is not rooted, but boot loader is unlocked, so it might be possible to root it. Still intrigued how one might identify apps refusing adb backup.

Comment: Note that a backup created with root requires restore with rot. So this would also affect the new installation.

Comment: Turns out upgrading only requires adb sideload, without erasing any data.

Comment: Should you need it again: my little tool [Adebar](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar) creates device documentation including listing installed apps ([examples here](https://izzy.codeberg.page/adebar/)). Apps having the `ALLOW_BACKUP` flag should allow backups, the others obviously not. As around Android 11/12 this got more granular, I'm not sure if the missing flag would mean no backups allowed at all, or how else the "partly backups" are marked (have neither Android 12 here not the time to investigate).